# Why does the output of pd.read_csv() and pd.read_excel() deliver a dataframe with different functioning column headers?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, xlsx

I'm importing an .xlsx file with `pd.read_excel()`. I received this .xlsx file as an CSV file and used excel to seperate it by comma so I get the proper .xlsx file with columns etc.  Six of the dataframe columns have a number as header (e.g. 5030, 5031,...). When I want to change the column name with `df = df.rename(columns={...})` this does not work. Also `df["5030"]` does not work, it throws an error: `KeyError:'5030'`. This code works for columns which have regular/non-integer names.

However, when I import the raw .csv file with `pd.read_csv()`, all the code above does work. I can just rename column names. The df's do look exactly the same when imported with both techniques, but apparently something is different.

It is not a serious issue as I can change the column name to non-integers manually in excel, but I'm very curious about what the underlying "problem" is here and how these two function operate in a different way.

Thanks!

Comment: Very hard to help without seeing some data and/or code. Also, df["5030"] will give a key error because 5030 is a number not a string. Try df[5030]

Comment: A guess, but I imagine that values in excel cells are assumed to be numeric unless formatted in some way, whereas in csv everything is a string as there is no way to specify data type.

Comment: @Will I think it is not necessary to give some data because I would like to know more about the fundamentals. I guess it makes sense that in a csv file everything is a string so that automatically makes the column headers a string

Comment: @Robvh your question asks about why your specific example has differences in Excel and CSV parsing. We can't really comment without seeing the headers.

Comment: The default for Pandas is to execute an inferring process to determine the appropriate data types for the data frame columns. This is the reason why your dataframes looks the same. But as for the headers data types it's look like there is a difference between the functions. If you will check the headers with `df.columns` you will see that in `read_excel` all convertible values were converted to integers while in `read_csv` they weren't. So, at least we got some clarification to your situation but you question is remain for headers.

Comment: Thank you Adirmola, this helps in the clarification that both functions differently convert certain values!

Comment: *I received this .xlsx file as an CSV file and used excel to seperate it by comma so I get the proper .xlsx file with columns etc*. Don't. Just don't. Excel is an excellent speadsheet tool, except for processing csv file. Just use any text editor including notepad to look at the csv file and know what it uses as delimiter and then load it with pandas `read_csv`. Passing by Excel it the best way to break all initial formatting without being noticed of anything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Serge. It is a dataset with a lot of columns and converting it a an excel files was way easier for me to delete some redundant columns and edit some columns header names. It appears that excel performed the conversion perfectly. Could you perhaps clarify a bit more? I used the converted file to do my analysis with. Do you mean that the results of this analysis is not to be trusted? The converted file looks good.